Quota exceeded for 'GenerateContent request limit per minute for a region' of service 'generativelanguage.googleapis.com'
This error started automatically after using app for a month.
binding.btnGenerate.setOnClickListener {
            if (binding.spinerTimer.isEnabled == false) {
                time = -1
            }
            binding.btnGenerate.isEnabled = false
            binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            val topic = binding.etTopic.text.toString()

            val generativeModel = GenerativeModel(
                // For text-only input, use the gemini-pro model
                modelName = "gemini-pro",
                // Access your API key as a Build Configuration variable (see "Set up your API key" above)
                apiKey = "*******************************"
            )
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { val ss = generativeModel.generateContent("hello ? ").text.toString()
            Log.i("hahah" , ss)}


            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                try {
                    var prompt =
                        "Make 10 MCQ on topic $topic in JSON format under list named 'quiz' and give 4 options under list named 'options' and also provide 'correctAnswer' for each.(carefully use quotation mark in key value pair.)  DO NOT USE WORD JSON AT BEGINNING"
                    if(topic == ""){
                        prompt = "Make 10 MCQ on random topic in JSON format under list named 'quiz' and give 4 options under list named 'options' and also provide 'correctAnswer' for each.(carefully use quotation mark in key value pair.)  DO NOT USE WORD JSON AT BEGINNING"
                    }
                    response = generativeModel.generateContent(prompt).text.toString()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("Generation", "Could not generate quiz")
                }
                val response1 = response.toString().replace("```", "")

                Log.i("TAGY", response1)

                val i = Intent(context, QuestionActivity::class.java)
                i.putExtra("quiz", response1)
                i.putExtra("time", time)
                startActivity(i)
                activity?.finish()
            }


        }

My console shows VALUE = 0 for 'GenerateContent request limit per minute for a region'
as far as i think i should switch to 'GenerateContent free tier input token count limit per model per minute'. But i dont know how. (I am new to Android development).
